# How to render LaTeX formulae in inkscape under OSX / mac?

Tags: inkscape, mac, osx, latex

I had trouble to find out how to render LaTeX formulae in inkscape under OSX / mac. I can imagine that many people are struggling with that, so lets collect the best solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.3/mac-os-x/dl/)
2. Install Tex-Live (or another TeX distro) via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) `brew install mactex`
3. Install pstoedit also via homebrew `brew install pstoedit`
4. Execute `export PATH=/usr/local/share/pstoedit:$PATH` in the Terminal
5. Download [TexText](https://inkscape.org/~jcwinkler/%E2%98%85textext)
6. Place the `.py` and the `.inx` file contained in the zip in the user extensions directory. The directory where the downloaded files need to be pasted is slightly different, depending on which kind of system you're using. To find it, look in `Edit menu > Preferences > System > User config`. Normally, it should be `/Users/USERNAME/.config/inkscape/extensions`
7. Restart inkscape and it should work.